# Detect when auto keying is turned on/off via Python?

Tags: python, add-on

I want to make it VERY obvious when auto keying is turned on in Blender. I want to write an add-on where, if auto keying is turned on, Blender's theme turns to Blender Light. Otherwise, Blender's theme is Blender Dark.

The core of the add-on is basically this:

```
if bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_keyframe_insert_auto == True:
    bpy.ops.script.execute_preset(menu_idname="USERPREF_MT_interface_theme_presets", filepath="C:\\Programs\\blender\\2.81\\scripts\\presets\\interface_theme\\blender_light.xml")
else:
    bpy.ops.script.execute_preset(menu_idname="USERPREF_MT_interface_theme_presets", filepath="C:\\Programs\\blender\\2.81\\scripts\\presets\\interface_theme\\blender_dark.xml")
```

Is it possible -- via an add-on -- to intercept when `use_keyframe_insert_auto` changes and then have this code execute? If so, how?

If that's not possible, what is the recommended way of handling this?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142313/bug-in-addon-to-change-header-color-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **message bus** subscription to do that.

The following script will call a function when *'use_keyframe_insert_auto'* is changing from the UI.

The principle is:

- Obtain a subscription link using `path_resolve` on the scene
- Then use this link to subscribe in order to fire a function when the value changes

Here is the code (look at the console to see the printed results):

```
import bpy

#The callback when use_keyframe_insert_auto changed
def a_callback(scene):
    print( scene, "use_keyframe_insert_auto changed" )

def subscribe_to_scene(scene):

    #Get a rna subscription link from the scene
    subscribe_to = scene.path_resolve("tool_settings.use_keyframe_insert_auto", False)

    #Effectively subscribe to the rna path from the scene
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=subscribe_to,
        owner=scene,
        args=(scene,),
        notify=a_callback,
    )

subscribe_to_scene(bpy.context.scene)
```